# Linux USB stick shows white noise screen on machine with AMD graphics card

Tags: linux, boot, kubuntu, amd

I installed Kubuntu 18.04 on a flash drive (I had 2 flash drives, one with the installer ISO from which I installed linux onto the other one) on a machine with an NVIDIA graphics card (GTX770, i7 4770K). The idea was to have a portable persistent operating system.

The problem is, when I try to boot from the stick on another machine with an AMD graphics card (HD7870, i5 4570) it shows the Kubuntu splash screen followed by corrupted white noise.

I already tried the following parameters in the GRUB menu: `radeon.nomodeset=0` and `nomodeset xforcevesa acpi=off nolapic` (basically a hail mary), the last one resulted in a persisent black screen (display was on though).

I did not install a proprietary NVIDIA driver (in fact I did not install any driver), so as far as I'm aware the kernel should just be able to load the suitable drivers, right? I also could not access other TTYs using CTRL+ALT+F1-9.

Comment: Fill a [bugreport](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)

Comment: Is there a problem [only] with the installed system in the second USB flash drive? If the live drive has working graphics in the other computer, one alternative is to create a **persistent live drive** using mkusb according to the following links [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) and [mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)